# Is it possible to create a Multiplayer Game using a Cloud Text File?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, google-cloud-platform, multiplayer

My idea is to create a multiplayer Pontoon game where I use a text file located in a Cloud Storage (like Google Drive etc). Each computer connected to the game should write to the file:

1. The user id / machine id - to identify which computer is associated with a player.
2. Game ID - to identify different groups of players playing different games.
3. Scores - To check which player has the highest scores.
4. Each of these variables written must be separated by a '|'

For example:

```
x = open(sample_file_online)
y = [i.split('|')[2] for i in x.readlines()] # Retrieves the score for each player.
x.close()
```

Is it really possible to read/write/append to a file like this? What methods are possible? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It's possible, but don't do it.  Use a database; this is exactly the sort of thing they're for, and they'll handle all sorts of problems that you'd otherwise have to solve for yourself with a text-file-based solution.

Comment: Could you be more explicit in what method should I use in databases (I really don't know much about them :0)?

Comment: Think of a database as being sort of like a Python dictionary, except persistent, and easily shared between different programs (e.g. different clients in a multiplayer game).  There are a bunch of cloud database options; since you mentioned Google Drive, I suggest looking at Firebase, which is Google's main cloud database solution.  Plenty of docs/tutorials out there to get you started!

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Storage is not a file system. It's a object storage. Whats the main difference?

To update a file on cloud storage you need download the file, update it, and upload again.

You have have a file system solution on Google Cloud named File Store.

BUT

You can do what you want using a Database, for instance Cloud Firestore.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/create-database-server-client-library?hl=pt-br#firestore_setup_dataset_pt1-python) you have some examples using several languages, inclusive Python.

See ya